# npm brunch stop functioning on ubuntu 12.04, 14.04, 14.10

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, ubuntu-12.04, brunch

I have been using brunch from more than 1 year in my application, from yesterday it has been observed that suddenly it has stopped functioning. I am getting error in return to an attempt to run the command "brunch watch"

```
No command 'brunch' found, did you mean:
 Command 'crunch' from package 'crunch' (universe)
 Command 'branch' from package 'rheolef' (universe)
brunch: command not found
```

So, I tried to install brunch again with command `sudo npm install -g brunch` which resulted in another error:

```
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.3.7
npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-color
npm ERR!     at RegClient.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:159:18)
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:57:9)
npm ERR!     at RegClient.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:137:16)
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:166:9)
npm ERR!     at RegClient.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:320:12)
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:246:65)
npm ERR!     at Request.self.callback (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:236:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:98:17)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:1142:14)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:117:20)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.16.0-38-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "brunch"
npm ERR! cwd /path/to/application
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.37
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Note: Above error log is from ubuntu 14.10 and node -v v0.10.37 and npm -v 1.4.28.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: this could help: https://github.com/brunch/brunch/issues/1004

Comment: Thanks @hassansin, it helped to get brunch functional once again.